# convert String Type to int,float,decimal etc Type on runtime C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have made a program in which i wanted to convert all values depending on parameters type which is get by run time methods, what i want is convert all values which are enter by user in textbox in define type of parameter. 
what i wanted is

```
private object convertType(Type type, string value)
    {
        Type t = typeof(int);
        //suppose value have stringvalue=33;
        return 33; //of type int
    }
```

is there any way to get any object type ?

**Updated Answer**

for @Atmane EL BOUACHRI,

```
class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {

   var ints =  ConvertType<int>("33");
   var bools = ConvertType<bool>("false");
   var decimals = ConvertType<decimal>("1.33m"); // exception here
   Console.WriteLine(ints);
   Console.WriteLine(bools);
    Console.WriteLine(decimals);

    Console.ReadLine();
 }

 public static T ConvertType<T>(string input)
 {
    T result =  default(T);
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if (converter != null)
    {
        try
        {
            result =  (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
        }
        catch 
        {
            // add you exception handling
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```

Here I don't want hard code `<int>`, `<string>` or `<decimal>`, what I want is

```
private object convertToAnyType(Type type, string value)
{
    //Type t = typeof(int);
    return ConvertType<type>("33");
}
```

Is there any way??

Comment: You'd likely have to use generics.

Comment: I have made dynamic web service call in which any web service is consume by my project, but i was stuck on parameters of different type, how can i handle all parameters of different methods?

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` will work for a limited range of built-in types

Answer (score 1):

You mean certainly return string value parsed to a specific Type. Then , I propose generics. Here's how :

1)- Without Generics (I Prefer With Generic in 2)-)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var ints = (int)ConvertType(typeof(int),"33"); 
            var bools = (bool)ConvertType(typeof(bool), "true");   

            Console.WriteLine(bools);
            Console.WriteLine(ints);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static object ConvertType(Type type, string input)
        {
            object result = default(object);
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
            if (converter != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    result = converter.ConvertFromString(input);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // add you exception handling
                }
            }
            return  result;
        }
    }
```

2)-With Generic

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

       var ints =  ConvertType<int>("33");
       var bools = ConvertType<bool>("false");
       var decimals = ConvertType<decimal>("1.33m"); // exception here
       Console.WriteLine(ints);
       Console.WriteLine(bools);
        Console.WriteLine(decimals);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static T ConvertType<T>(string input)
    {
        T result =  default(T);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        if (converter != null)
        {
            try
            {
                result =  (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
            }
            catch 
            {
                // add you exception handling
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hpe it helps

Comment: In my case this is not working

int t = 0;
            int ints = oo.ConvertType<t.GetType()>("33");

Comment: @user6002727  I dont understand

Comment: I don't know which type is come from other end, so how can i call this function as "convertType<g.GetType>" , where g is any variable like int, float etc

Comment: @user6002727 give me an concret exemple.. You should have a type anyway. a String or Object.

Comment: Updated my post, please review

Comment: if i want 1st one logic with generic, so how I could that? means ConvertType<typeof(int)) scenerio?

Comment: Finally , I find that converting a run time type into a compile time type  is not possible.